# Sending BTC 3 times to the same address - 2 times success - one time not received

Tags: lost-transactions

I sent BTC to the same address on three different occasions. The first two times were successful. The third time (yesterday) the receiver claimed that he did not receive the BTC. It took over an hour until my wallet gave me confirmation that the transaction was successful. How can I independently verify that the receiver did in fact receive the 3rd transaction? Thx

Receiver address: `184wkr7Jxf6EM2ivFRh2Cy8iiwkCzuFTwV`

Comment: You could use a block explorer (e.g., https://blockstream.info/) and search for the ID of each transaction you transmitted. It could be the case that the 3rd transaction has not been confirmed yet and is still in the mempool if the associated fees were not competitive.